# Как вставить изображение в javaFX приложение?

Tags: javafx, изображения

Задача, просто вставить приложение javafx изображение, 
Код:

```
stage.setTitle("Image");
   FlowPane root = new FlowPane ();
   root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

   Image image = new Image ("C:\\Users\\MKS\\Desktop\\picture\\Hello.JPEG");
   ImageView view = new ImageView (image);
   root.getChildren().add(view);
   stage.setScene(new Scene (root, 400, 400));
   stage.show();
```

Указываю путь к изображению и всё, ничего не работает. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Путь к изображению следует указать так:

```
Image("file:/C:/Users/MKS/Desktop/picture/Hello.JPEG");
```